# Low-frequency amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I am having some trouble with a low frequency amplifier and I don't know how to handle the situation.

[image]

I should have a 10x amplification all the time but it only works for the positive side of things.

[image]

Do you guys have any advice? Or do you see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried standing on my head but I toppled over!

Make Q45 a PNP transistor.

Swap over the emitter and collector of Q43

Comment: It seems to work, thank you!