# Low-frequency amplifier capping out

Tags: amplifier, voltage-amplification

I can't figure out why this amplifier is capping out

[image]

[image]

Aditional details:

I can identify 4 waveforms that resemle the output
1st:
[image]
[image]

2nd:

Base of Q42

Waveform same as 1st

3rd:

[image]
[image]

And 4th

[image]

Waveform same as 3rd

The rest of them besides Vout were just straight lines.

Comment: Q43 appears to be an incorrect part or incorrectly connected.

Comment: Probe internal nodes with your AC analysis, not just the input and output.   You'll find the stage it's clipping at.

Comment: BTW, "generally" it's considered best to draw your schematics with (+) voltages at the top, and (-) or GND at the bottom.   Your very lowest voltage rail (-12V) is at the top and your most positive (+12) is at the bottom.  Makes it hard to read.

Comment: Q43 is a QBC817-25 and the only other option I have is a BC846B. It seems to be conected where it should. Or at least where my professor says it should.

Comment: There are too many parts for the max output power of only 0.6W.

Comment: Appears to be the same amplifier as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/642502/low-frequency-amplifier. And Q43 still seems to be reversed. This really needs to show intermediate waveforms to determine where problem may lie. There should not be clipping at less than 5V peak with 12V rails.

Comment: I added some intermediate waveforms by editing the question.

Comment: Can't you try reversing Q43 E and C? Or use a PNP BC807. Still hard to analyze with positive and negative rails upside down.

Comment: Incidentally, the word for what you're talking about is "clipping", not "capping out". You could also say "saturating"; I've just never heard "capping out" before and was wondering what that meant before seeing the pictures.

Comment: PStechPaul is correct, Q43, the VAS, should be an NPN but the emitter and collector should be swapped. A useful clue is that the Miller cap C1 should be between the base and collector. Just flip Q43 around the other way and see what results you get.

Comment: @DinuVA Would you walk me through your thinking with this schematic? (I sure hope it isn't copied from the web -- it's just wrong.) I'd like to listen for a moment to you about what you understand or think you do so that I have an idea of how to better help. GodClara, sorry I mean GodJihyo, has it dead to rights. Your VAS has one foot in the right place and the other foot somewhere it should not ought to be. And that's not the only issue I see. So I need to listen to you talk about how you arrived at this schematic.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious problem, as noted in the comments, is that the VAS (Voltage Amplifier Stage) transistor is connected incorrectly.

Once you get that straightened out you need to look at the biasing. From what I can tell it looks like your bias currents are too high. The input stage looks to be around 20 mA, I would cut that down to 1 to 2 mA. The VAS stage should be maybe 5 to 10 mA.

One way to find the best bias points is to replace the transistor constant current sources with a constant current source model in the simulator, then step the CCS and see at what value you get the least distortion. Do one at a time, Q40 for the input stage, Q41 for the VAS stage, and Q42 for the class A stage. Using the built-in current source allows you to easily change it for testing. Once you get the values correct you can put the transistor ones back in and adjust them to get the correct currents.